# Command-Line Compilation

Tags: .net, shellexecute

I'm trying to make a program, which would run `cl.exe` (C/C++ compiler) and compile a C++ program. Here's my code:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Shell("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ _ 
        bin\cl.exe /EHsc ""C:\myprogram.cpp"" ")

        Console.WriteLine("Compilation Succeded")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

This doesn't compile the .cpp file. Do you have any ideas how to make this work?

**EDIT:** I entered "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe" /EHsc "C:\myprogram.cpp" in CMD and it didn't compile, but instead it threw an error ( This application has failed to start because mspdb100.dll was not found. )

**EDIT:** I executed my program trough 'VS Command Prompt' and it compiled my program (it showed that it compiled), but there's no compiled exe and obj files.

Comment: "_This doesn't compile the .cpp file._" -- What does it do?  What errors are you getting?  Any output?

Comment: It does nothing. No errors, no output except the "Compilation Succeded" which is written by my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, instead of using cl.exe I'm now using MSBuild. Much better.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe`.

This path will change depending on the installed version of Visual Studio, the bitness of the OS, and the system drive.
You can find the path in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\InstallDir`.
On my machine, it's `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\`.

`CL.exe` isn't compiling your program because you have an incorrect command-line.
In particular, you probably need to surround the source path in double-quotes, not single-quotes.
To use double-quotes inside a string literal, double them: `".../EHsc ""Path.cpp"" "`

Comment: I used double-quotes in my program. How to pass the .cpp file to cl.exe? ("Shell("C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe /EHsc myprogram.cpp")" doesn't work.

Comment: @Cobold: You need to pass the full path to your file.

Answer (score 0):

single ticks `'` cannot be used on a command line for files containing spaces.  Try using double quotes `"` instead:

```
Shell("cl /EHsc ""a .cpp file"" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into issues with spaces in the path for `cl.exe`.  Try:

```
Shell("""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\cl.exe"" /EHsc ""myprogram.cpp"" ")
```

Also make sure that `myprogram.cpp` is in the current directory for the program's run (or specify the full path to it on the command line).